# Can't see images in internet explorer

Tags: c#, html, internet-explorer

I have a site I've built, and I just can't see the images there in IE only. In chrome it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Report</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <img width="215" height="62" src="Report_files/image293.png" />
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <img width="257" height="75" src="Report_files/image310.jpg" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <img width="776" height="9" src="Report_files/image318.gif" />
        <br />
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            Report - Protein Expression<br />
            1111111111 <br /><br />

        </div>
        <div>
            Application Details<br />
            Application: Protein Expression<br />
            <img width="382" height="245" src="Report_files/Plate.gif" /><br />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can see the first three images, but not the Plate.gif one.

EDIT:
Actually, I cannot see this image in internet explorer at all even when directly accessing it!

EDIT 2:
I found out that I create the image using C# code. My guess is that the images are created with a wrong header or something. Here is the code:

```
Size size = new Size( panelPlateDrawing1.Size.Width + ucColorMapLegend1.Size.Width, 
                Math.Max(panelPlateDrawing1.Size.Height, ucColorMapLegend1.Size.Height) );

            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);

            panelPlateDrawing1.DrawToBitmap(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, panelPlateDrawing1.Size.Width, panelPlateDrawing1.Size.Height));

            ucColorMapLegend1.DrawToBitmap(img, new Rectangle(panelPlateDrawing1.Size.Width, 0, ucColorMapLegend1.Size.Width, ucColorMapLegend1.Size.Height));

            return img;
```

Comment: Check the case of the file name I *think* IE is case sensitive.

Comment: Also please add some `alt` attributes to you images.

Comment: Checked + added alt, same problem.

Comment: right click on the image (red cross holding image) and click 'Properties' what does it say is the address of the image?

Comment: im not big on c# (heted it at uni) but maybe the file type is wrong? try changin it to other types (gif, jpg, png, etc). See if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when Internet Explorer (or any browser) doesn't show an image, it's because it's in a format it doesn't understand, and as you don't show how you're saving these images to disk, probably, as you already guessed, they're with the worng headers or information; to solve it you need to save them in the proper format, more information about how to do this can be seen here: [Bmp to jpg/png in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665/bmp-to-jpg-png-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Actually I've found this exact stackoverflow question by myself 20 minutes before you posted it, but you guessed it right. +1 and correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe case sensitivity problem. Validate file names.